# Mongoose opens only some collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I just started using mongoose library in my projects, but a big problem appears.
I have many collections in a database and when I use find or aggregate in some of them it works perfectly, but not in others:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
modelo =  new mongoose.model('usuarios', new mongoose.Schema({}));

await mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true  })

modelo.find().then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)   // It has data with some collections, with others [] even though it has data
})
```

When I change the collection name with another name it doesn´t work, Its the same database and it works with 5 of my 10 collections. If a collection returns data, it always returns data, with the others I dropped, re-created, and nothing.

The obvious questions: They exist, they have data, they were created the same way.

The user has read/write access to all the databases

I also tried using the schemas with all their fields, and the same answer ( also many combinations I imagined could work).

Now, when I use :

```
  mongoose.connection.db.collection(collectionName,async (err,actualColection)=>{
    const xx=await actualColeccion.find().toArray()
    console.log(xx)     //  yeah !!!  it returns data
})
```

It works fine, it returns data.

Question :

1. Is that a mongoose error ?
2. Is there a better way to find data in a mongo database?
3. Is there a better package than mongoose ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

pd: listCollections returns :

```
[
  {
    name: 'menues',          // returns data
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },
  {
    name: 'servicios',       // returns data 
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_', ns: 'suiteMBC.servicios' }
  },
  {
    name: 'usuariosPalm',    // returns [] but it has data even though it has ns ( namespace I suppose)
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_', ns: 'suiteMBC.usuariosPalm' }
  },
  {
    name: 'contratos',       // returns data
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },
  {
    name: 'maepro',          // returns [] but it has data
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },
  {
    name: 'maepr',           // returns [] but it has data
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },
  {
    name: 'txitem',         // returns [] but it has data
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },
  {
    name: 'empresas',       // returns data 
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_', ns: 'suiteMBC.empresas' }
  },
  {
    name: 'maeproxx',           // returns [] but it has data
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },
  {
    name: 'usuarios',           // returns data 
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_', ns: 'suiteMBC.usuarios' }
  }
]
```

Comment: I suspect its the usual trouble of model name and collection name being different (mongoose does auto-plurals). Can you list the 'collection' names you have tried? `maepr`, e.g., is not a plural, so you can't access it via mongoose model `maepr`, because mongoose would probably make this `maeprs` for the collection name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect its the usual trouble of model name and collection name being different (mongoose does auto-plurals). Can you list the 'collection' names you have tried? maepr, e.g., is not a plural, so you can't access it via mongoose model maepr, because mongoose would probably make this maeprs for the collection name.

Try setting the collection name explicitly, e.g.:

```
modelo =  new mongoose.model('maepr', new mongoose.Schema({}), 'maepr');
```

Comment: That´s exactly what was happening friend, ( I was trying to figure it out 3 days) thank you very much.

Comment: It's very confusing! I wish they didn't try to be so "smart".

Comment: Yes, in fact, an s does not mean plural, there are many words that don't have an s at the end and are plural ( people, mice, etc, and thats just english, I code in spanish ).  Worst idea ever...

Comment: agreed! Look at these "pluralization" rules they have. Nuts! https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/d5a0d373b35f770cae6e1fc628079e3e63433e9f/lib/utils.js#L32-L62 -- foreign languages being a perfect counter-argument to such an insane idea.